# How do I simplify this nested generic typed class

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface IHasFeature<TFeature> { 
    TFeature Feature { get; set; } 
}
public class FeatureOne { 
    /*...*/ 
}
public class ProductOne : IHasFeature<FeatureOne> { 
    public FeatureOne Feature { get; set; } 
}
public abstract class BaseContainer<TProduct, TFeature> 
where TProduct : IHasFeature<TFeature> {
    public TProduct Product { get; set; }
    public void DoProcess() { 
        var result = Product.Feature.Execute(); //Execute is an extension method
    } 
}
public class MyContainer : BaseContainer<ProductOne, FeatureOne> { 
    /*...*/ 
}
```

**Works when I do**:

```
MyContainer : BaseContainer<ProductOne, FeatureOne>
```

**But I want to**:

```
MyContainer : BaseContainer<ProductOne>
```

`ProductOne : IHasFeature<...>` should already contain the nested generic feature `TFeature`, I don't want to repeat them again in `MyContainer` construction.

Any idea how I can improve this? Thanks.

EDIT2 -----------------------

Removed new keyword, it was wrong as Nenad said.

Comment: First of all, why is `IHasFeature` generic when you're not using the generic type at all? Couldn't it be standard non-generic interface instead? It would solve your problem.

Comment: Should features, like `FeatureOne`, inherit from common interface `IFeature`?

Comment: Your container is expecting some features, how do you want to tell it what features to expect? In your "but I want to" section how should "MyContainer" know what to verify? You say that `ProductOne` knows about `FeatureOne` but then you want to verify that a product has a feature, that it already has. This doesn't make sense to me, or probably I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @all, Sorry, i mixed up my coding. Edited the post. please try again.

Comment: @Nenad yes I could, but not necessarily, they can be plain POCOs to make it simple. Or if I do, I can go public interface IHasFeature<TFeature> where TFeature : IFeatrure ... like that. But that is not where my problem is from.

Comment: `MyContainer` doesn't have any generic parameters so your example won't compile. However, the compiler won't infer generic parameters like this, so if you have N parameters, you have to specify them all.

Comment: @Tom btw, this initializer works with your code `new MyContainer();`, not `new MyContainer<ProductOne, FeatureOne>();`. Can you fix example, maybe clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile translates your call to the extension method `Execute()` as a call to the static method of the class where it is defined. So, when you call `Product.Feature.Execute()` inside `DoProcess()`, the compiler needs to know the type of `Product.Feature` in order to call the appropriate extension method.

What I suggest is write `IHasFeature` like this

```
public interface IHasFeature
{
    void DoSomethingWithFeature();
}
```

If you want to keep `IHasFeature` generic, the best you can do is define `BaseContainer` without specifying `TFeature` and implement `DoProcess()` in `MyContainer`.

```
public abstract class BaseContainer<TProduct>
{
    public TProduct Product { get; set; }
    public abstract void DoProcess();
}

public class MyContainer : BaseContainer<ProductOne>
{
    public override void DoProcess()
    {
        Product.Feature.Execute();
    }
}
```